# Shutdown NOT super-user?

Tags: terminal, bash, ssh, script, shutdown

I'm trying to shutdown Macs after 24 hours of runtime with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
BOOT_TIME=$(sysctl -n kern.boottime | sed -e 's/.* sec = \([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
CURR_TIME=$(date +%s)
MAX_UPDAYS=1 #Days

DAYS_UP=$(( ( $CURR_TIME - $BOOT_TIME) / 86400 ))
    if [ $DAYS_UP -ge ${MAX_UPDAYS} ];then
        echo Mac is going to shutdown 
        shutdown -h now
    else
        echo No shutdown needed
fi
```

The file name is  `ShutdownUPTIME.sh`.
Now when I try to type in:

```
sudo ssh ADMIN@macxxx 'bash -s' < ./documents/ShutdownUPTIME.sh
```

it wants a password. I type that in and then the script runs. The only thing that pops up though is:

> shutdown: NOT super-user

The user is in the sudoers file as ALL=(ALL) ALL on both Macs.
Any ideas?

Comment: Users into the sudoers file still need to run `sudo shutdown` on the target machine

Comment: Related: [how to use ssh to run shell script on a remote machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine). Check the comments for local scripts requiring sudo on the remote machine to execute them there.

Answer (score 3):

You are running `ssh` command locally as root and the remote bash (hence the whole script) as the user `ADMIN@macxxx` (without switching to root on the remote server).

You must precede either `bash` or `shutdown` with `sudo` (provided `ADMIN` has passwordless sudo permissions for `shutdown` or all commands on `macxxx` machine).

So either:

```
ssh ADMIN@macxxx 'sudo bash -s' < ./documents/ShutdownUPTIME.sh
```

Or:

```
...
if [ $DAYS_UP -ge ${MAX_UPDAYS} ];then
    echo Mac is going to shutdown 
    sudo shutdown -h now
else
...
```

Comment: I only used the ssh connection. But I wanted to show my script in case something is wrong with the script. So I just use ssh ADMIN@macxxx 'sudo bash -s' < ./documents/ShutdownUPTIME.sh, but it says I am not a super user. My user is in the sudoers file as ALL=(ALL) ALL, on both the local and the remote Mac.

Comment: From the message you cited now, `ADMIN` does not have sudo permissions on the `macxxx`.

Comment: Yes he has. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: So include the relevant information I the question, not in the comments to an answer. If the system refuses to change the user with `sudo`, it means the user has no permissions. In the commands you included in the question, you don't even try to use sudo on the remote machine.