# Shutdown "no tty present and no askpass program specified"?

Tags: mac, bash, ssh, shutdown

I'm trying to run a shutdown script remotely on multiple Macs. The command I use to start it over ssh is:

```
ssh ADMIN@mac123 'bash -s' sudo < ./documents/ShutdownUPTIME.sh
```

Of course it asks me for an sudo password, which I type in correctly. The only message after that is: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Any ideas how I can fix this?
My user is definitely a super-user

Answer (score 2):

The error message appears when you try to run a command inside your bash call with `sudo` and, although the user `ADMIN` on the destination system `mac123` has permissions to run commands with `sudo`, the option `NOPASSWD` is not specified for this particular user (in `/etc/sudoers`).

System would have to prompt user and wait for the password to be provided from the keyboard, however as no terminal is attached, the prompt would hang forever.

As a measure against such situation, system fails with the error message you got.

---

If you took time to understand my [yesterday's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264509/145449):

> provided ADMIN has **passwordless** sudo permissions for shutdown or all commands on macxxx machine)

You wouldn't run into this problem.

You should modify your script:

```
...
if [ $DAYS_UP -ge ${MAX_UPDAYS} ];then
    echo Mac is going to shutdown 
    sudo shutdown -h now
else
...
```

And edit the sudoers file on `mac123`, so that it contains, for example (it must match the command in the script):

```
ADMIN ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Bear in mind that you **must do it using `visudo`** program, otherwise you will likely break your system completely.

---

Alternatively you can use `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable and point it to a script providing the password (the second part of the error message). I do not recommend this method.