# Error when using `sudo shutdown` on remote machine

Tags: terminal, macos, sudo

I'm remotely shutting down a bunch of Macs by using `ssh` to execute the `shutdown` command on each of them. I've asked the question before ([Shutdown "no tty present and no askpass program specified"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264663/shutdown-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified)) and got it working by adding `ADMIN ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -h now` to the sudoers files as recommended.

In the meantime two of the remote Macs got upgraded to Sierra and I again get

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

even though the line in the sudoers file is still there.

What do I need to change to make this work with Sierra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper solution for your remote shutdown script is the following:

Script (please adjust the MAX_UPSEC value, for testing purposes I used a low value):

```
#!/bin/bash
BOOT_TIME=$(sysctl -n kern.boottime | sed -e 's/.* sec = \([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
CURR_TIME=$(date +%s)
MAX_UPSEC=300 #Seconds

SECS_UP=$(($CURR_TIME - $BOOT_TIME))
    if [ $SECS_UP -ge ${MAX_UPSEC} ];then
        echo "Mac is going to shutdown because it is already $SECS_UP seconds running"
        shutdown -h now
    else
        echo "No shutdown needed because the Mac is only $SECS_UP seconds up"
fi
```

If you run the shutdown script (assuming the script is located at ~/bin/sh/) with the following command:

```
ssh admusr@host  'sudo bash -s' < /Users/admusr/bin/sh/ShutdownUPTIME.sh
```

the proper sudoers lines on the remote hosts are then

```
root        ALL = (ALL) ALL
%admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL
admusr      ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash
```